# Which process is MmsSmsProvider in?

Tags: android

android stored the sms in `mmssms.db` which uid and gid is radio(1001). if app wishes to read the sms which should call sms content provider to do. My question is which process has `MmsSmsProvider`? I wonder this process should have a high permission(root or in radio group). I guess this process could be `system_server` or `com.android.phone`. since `system_server` is in radio group and the uid and gid of `com.android.phone` is radio.

I read the source code `MmsSmsProvider.java` that is in package of `com.android.providers.telephony`. I also find the `TelephonyProvider.apk` in `/system/app`. but I still didn't find which process launch the `TelephonyProvider.apk`

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined by the Android Manifest for TelephonyProvider:

http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/packages/providers/TelephonyProvider/AndroidManifest.xml

```
18        package="com.android.providers.telephony"
19        coreApp="true"
20        android:sharedUserId="android.uid.phone">
```

android.uid.phone is considered RADIO_UID by the rules in PackageManagerService:

http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#1304

```
    mSettings.addSharedUserLPw("android.uid.phone", RADIO_UID,
            ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM|ApplicationInfo.FLAG_PRIVILEGED);
```

The application is started by the system in the early boot phase as android.uid.phone is associated with the TelephonyStack which for any radio device is super important.